# How to run all my python scripts throw proxy

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, proxy, environment-variables

I'm facing the issue, when i try to run my python scripts which require to connect Internet on 80, 443 port, im getting connection timeout, actually i need to run my scrips throw proxy.

I tried to set proxy settings using various method:

- 1) use export command and set
  `http_proxy/https_proxy/HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY` with the value
- 2) add new records to `/etc/environment`
- 3) add new records to
  `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Python code:

```
import urllib3 
http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
r = http.request('GET', 'httpbin.org/robots.txt') 
r.data
```

This is sample of my code. I'm running this scripts in a clean ubuntu docker image.

Other then that. I can connect to the internet with my docker image throw proxy, for example curl from command line can establish connection to other websites.

Comment: Could you please add your code as well. Otherwise it's hard to assist in answering your question.
Another question: how is this related to `docker`?

Comment: Please add your code to the question and do not post it as a comment. Please also post your docker-compose file or the sequence of commands that you use for running the docker container.
Can you connect from inside your docker container to the internet at all? What records have you added, see step 2) and 3) ?